# SQL Query Help Needed

Tags: add-on, database, mysql, queries, mx-google-map

During a migration from 1x to 2x on an EE site, I needed to switch to current Google Maps add-ons and chose MX Google Maps (for now anyway). The site was using a geotagger that filled a Latitude field and Longitude field with data, so those are still in place.

Since MX Google Maps uses it's own fields, I need to find a way to migrate current db data to MX Maps. But I'm hella bad at this SQL query stuff.

Right now, the lat/lon are stored in exp_channel_data in field_id_41 (lat) and field_id_42 (lon). MX Maps stores Lat/Lon in field_id_46 as a pipe delimited set (lat|lon). It also stores data for each entry in it's own table at exp_mx_google_map.

In exp_mx_google_map it has

- point_id (a sequential number for each post)
- entry_id (tied to the entry itself)
- latitude
- longitude
- address (not using)
- city (not using)
- zipcode (not using)
- state (not using)
- field_id (in this case 46)
- icon

With about 2400 entries storing lat/lon, what's the best way to go about moving this data over? Besides drinking heavily and sleeping on it, which I've tried and doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That should be as simple as this, using the correct `channel_id`:

```
Update exp_channel_data
set field_id_46 = concat(field_id_41, '|', field_id_42)
where channel_id = 1
```

For the Maps table, it's something like this:

```
Insert into exp_mx_google_map
(entry_id, lat, long, some_example_field)
Select entry_id, field_id_41, field_id_42, 'Some example value'
from exp_channel_data
where channel_id = 1
```

You can fill in the other fields from there.

**Updated:** Sorry, the `values` line caused an error in the `Insert` statement. I've updated that.

I only included a few sample fields in that. You'll want to be sure to map the rest. Note that you can pass your own values, they don't all have to be from fields.

As UltraBob suggested, you can use PHPMyAdmin, Sequel Pro, Navicat, etc to set the `point_id` field to `AUTO_INCREMENT`. You don't need to include it in your `insert` then. It will get a value as each record is created.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the first one ran perfectly. Getting a syntax error on the second one. Wil the second one add the sequential point_id?

Comment: is `auto_increment` set on the point_id column?

Comment: I don't think you need two cancats in that first update query.  That can be `set field_id_46 = concat(field_id_41, '|', field_id_42)`

Comment: @UltraBob - You're right about the concat. I must've had something else stuck in my head. Maybe Google Docs. Kelly Sims - Updated with some additional notes.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for the help both of you. Now I'm running into an issue where even though the database is set right, posts aren't outputting the map unless I edit that entry and save it. Is this an EE issue, or something else?

Comment: It sounds like there's something missing in your entries. Possibly within the Insert statement for the special table, or in exp_channel_data. Saving the entries is setting that value for you.

Comment: (Please be sure to mark this answer as the solution.)

Comment: Not sure. I've gone through the exp_channel_data table and there doesn't seem to be any difference between entries I save (and haven't changed) vs. entries that had been updated by the query and not re-saved. One odd thing, I posted a new entry with map data. The exp_mx_google_maps auto-increment field is 2048, while last entry from the query stops at 1344.